# A port scanner or proxy server for testing UDP (or all other) protocols on particular (or all) ports

Tags: scanner, udp

I have a problem GPS localizer (TK102), that is probably sending out data over UDP, but my server isn't receiving it (while it does from other clients, using UDP and this IP/port).

I asked on [Unix/Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47332/scan-one-or-all-ports-on-udp-or-all-protocols-to-see-if-im-getting-what-i-su) on how could I try to solve this on server side.

But I would also ask here, if there is any solution for Windows, that I could use on my home computer (after redirecting localizer to that computer's IP instead of servers one) to intercept/trace/check, if it is really sending anything, and if any -- then what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is pretty much the same for every operating system. Run a packet sniffer on the server (for Windows there are for instance [`Windump`](http://www.winpcap.org/windump/) or [`Wireshark`](http://www.wireshark.org/)). `Windump` example:

```
C:\> windump -D
1.\Device\NPF_{FD6B99B9-2B36-4222-A1C3-59C52DE63BB1} (Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter)

C:\> windump -i 1 -XX udp
windump: listening on \Device\NPF_{FD6B99B9-2B36-4222-A1C3-59C52DE63BB1}
...
```

Then send UDP packets to your server from another host:

```
hping3 SERVER --udp -p 2342 -c 1 -n
```

or

```
nmap -sU -n -Pn -p 2342 SERVER
```

and see if the packet sniffer logs those packets.

Comment: Thanks! As I wrote, I also asked similar question on [Linux/Unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47332/scan-one-or-all-ports-on-udp-or-all-protocols-to-see-if-im-getting-what-i-su) on how to solve it on server side. But I had to answer myself! :] If solution described there fail, I'll for sure force my localizer to send data to my home computer and use your method of analysing packets.